# Intersection of chord with circle knowing the length and a point

Tags: geometry, analysis, recreational-mathematics, circles

Let's take a circle with radius ***R***, and center in *O (0, 0)*. We take on this circle a point ***A*** with coordinates ***xA*** and ***yA***.

We know that point ***A*** is one of the endings of a chord with length ***l***.

Which is the easiest method to find the intersections points with circle ***B*** and ***C***, knowing this information?

Basically I think that the following sistem has to be solved in ***x*** and ***y***.

\begin{matrix}
 l = \sqrt{(x_A - x)^2 + (y_A - y)^2}\\ 
 x^2 + y^2 = R^2& 
\end{matrix}

See my drawing bellow, too. It's just an example.
[image: The great circle]

I will give special thanks for who will solve this problem. It's a project for computer science that I will make it open source, when  will it be finished.

Comment: You are essentially asking how to find the intersection points of two circles, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And, the project is open source!

Sure, it's not finished but, it starts working.

Follow it on Github: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/circular-mirror

Thank you for [@mixedmath](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9754/mixedmath)'s suggestion: "You are essentially asking how to find the intersection points of two circles, right?" ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344052/intersection-of-chord-with-circle-knowing-the-length-and-a-point/351903#comment740176_344052))

A screen shot with the app:

[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you know $\angle{CAB}$, then you should be able to find $\angle{BOC}$ using the fact that (angle at circumference is half angle at centre):
$$\angle{CAB} = 0.5\angle{BOC}$$

Say the lowest point of the circle is X. $\angle{COX} = 0.5\angle{BOC}$ (by symmetry). Now, the coordinates $(x_C,y_C)$ simply become:
$$x_C = R\sin{\angle{COX}}$$
$$y_C = -R\cos{\angle{COX}}$$

Similarly, for $(x_B,y_B)$:
$$x_B = -R\sin{\angle{BOX}}$$
$$y_B = -R\cos{\angle{BOX}}$$

Those are derived from:
$$\sin(A) = \frac{Opp}{Hyp}$$
$$\cos(A) = \frac{Adj}{Hyp}$$

Comment: +1, for answer, but finally I followed the [@mixedmath](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/9754/mixedmath)'s suggestion. ([link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344052/intersection-of-chord-with-circle-knowing-the-length-and-a-point/351903#comment740176_344052)). See my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine.  I will use $L$ as the lower case looks too much like a $1$  You have $$L^2=(x_A-x_B)^2+(y_A-y_B)^2\\ x_B^2+y_B^2=R^2\\L^2-R^2-x_A^2-y_A^2=-2x_Ax_B-2y_Ay_B\\x_B=\frac 1{2x_A}(-2y_Ay_B+R^2+x_A^2+y_A^2-L^2)$$

Now square that, equate it to $R^2-y_B^2$ and you have a quadratic in $y_B$

An alternate approach is to use polar conversion.  The angle at the center that the chord represents is $2 \arcsin \frac L{2R}$.  So find the angle that $A$ is at, using ATAN2$(x_A,y_A)$ add and subtract the angle of the chord, and convert back to rectangular by $x = R \cos \theta, y=R \sin \theta$  This is certainly easier to program.

Comment: Replace *xB* by *x*, because it will take two values. What about if xA is 0? The case has to be solved.

Comment: @John:  yes, you will find two values for $x_B$, in fact there may be four.  One will be $x_B$, one will be $x_C$ and the others will be spurious.  If $x_A=0$ it simplifies a great deal because you can then easily make each of the first two $x_B^2=$ and eliminate $x_B$ that way.

Comment: I would like to write for me the equation of second grade in xB, yB, to view it clear. Thank you. When I will finish the problem I will mark an answer as correct. :-) I know the angle CAB. If you find an easier solution post it.

Comment: +1, for answer, but finally I followed the [@mixedmath](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/9754/mixedmath)'s suggestion. ([link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344052/intersection-of-chord-with-circle-knowing-the-length-and-a-point/351903#comment740176_344052)). See my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Spent some time on it and finally wrestled it into a quadratic equation...[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcRO2.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Here is a [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/947379).